# Ignoring positive (semi)definite condition for optimization

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, optimization, matrix-calculus

Suppose I have a smooth scalar-valued objective function $f(\cdot)$ defined on the space of $n \times n$ matrices. I want to solve the optimization problem $\min_{A \geq 0} f(A)$ where $A \geq 0 $ means that $A$ is positive semidefinite. It is easy to calculate the (matrix) derivative of $f(\cdot)$ if I ignore the constraint $A \geq 0 $. Let $f'(A)$ (which is a $n \times n$ matrix)   denote this derivative, and suppose I proceed by finding $A \geq 0$ such that $f'(A) = 0$. Is this a valid approach?

In short, will I still get the critical points right even if I calculate the derivative ignoring the constraint that $A \geq 0$?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Tell us what your objective function is, and what values of n you want to solve.

Answer (score 1):

No, you are ignoring the boundary. Your technique works for an unconstrained problem, however in a constrained setting the optimal solution doesn't have to have a zero gradient (it does require that the directional derivative is non-negative in all directions). Moreover, since you did not state if the objective function $f$ is convex or not, this is only a necessary condition, it might not be sufficient.

However, your problem can still be solvable. In case the objective function is linear, then you have a [semidefinite program](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semidefinite_programming). Even if $f$ is not linear, since your single constraint is convex, then you have a convex domain that even has a closed-form projection solution, so you can use some variant of gradient projection / proximal gradient to solve the problem. If $f$ is convex, you can find the global minimum, else you might have to settle for a stationary point.

In case you take the gradient projection approach, the projection onto the set of PSD matrices is $P_T(A)=U[\Lambda(A)]_+U^T$, where $A=U\Lambda U^T$ is the spectral decomposition of $A$, and $[\Lambda(A)]_+$ means the maximum between the diagonal elements of $\Lambda$ (eigenvalues of $A$) and zero, applied per element.

Notice that in both cases (PSD programming, gradient projection), the solution involves an eigenvalues decomposition at each stet, and is therefore suitable for medium-size problems.

Comment: Thanks for the response! I'm pretty new to this stuff; do you mind pointing me to a few references? The gradient projection approach seems promising, but a quick google search seems to imply that this works only in highly specialized cases.

Comment: This might be a quick starting reference: https://tlienart.github.io/pub/csml/cvxopt/pgd.html.  Most resources refer to vector spaces, but the applying it to the symmetric matrix space is pretty straight forward. However, to get a deeper understanding you will need to get familiar with convex analysis and optimization algorithms. If you have access to academic resources, then look for *Bertsekas, D. P.* "Nonlinear programming" and "Convex Analysis and Optimization". You can also post the explicit problem you're trying to solve and I suggest a general scheme for it.

Comment: Also Boyd's Convex Optimization book is helpful and is available online: https://web.stanford.edu/~boyd/cvxbook/bv_cvxbook.pdf. It's great for the convex analysis part, however the algorithms section is more focused on Interior Point Methods (IPMs), which in my opinion, are less suitable for what you're trying to do here

Comment: Thanks again. I'll look into those books. The problem I have is a minimization problem $\min_{A} f(A)$ under the constraint that $ A \geq 0 $. The objective function $f$ is nonconvex so I don't think I can really prove things or definitively claim that some algorithm is going to find the global minimum in the context. However, $f$ is smooth ($C^\infty$). I'm trying to find an algorithm that "works" in this scenario.

Comment: On a related note, is simply using the Cholesky decomposition and treating the problem as an unconstrained one a bad idea?

Comment: Gradient projection definitely works for non-convex objectives, however we can only guarantee convergence to a stationary point. Regarding Cholesky decomposition, how will it convert the problem to an unconstrained one? Will be interesting to show such a formulation

Comment: Maybe I'm confused. Isn't $\min_{A \geq 0} f(A) = \min_{L: \text{lower triangular}} f(LL^T)$? The problem on the right-hand side is then unconstrained with respect to the $n(n+1)/2$ "vector" $L$.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you wish to make the change $A=LL^T$. However, $L$ is not some random matrix, it is a lower triangular matrix. Therefore you have a new constraint ($L$:lower triangular), which is probably more difficult to handle than your original PSD constraint. While change of variables is a commonly used and helpful technique, it is only effective if it makes it easier to solve the problem. I'm not sure this is the case we have here.

Comment: Well, we can view $L$ as an $n(n+1)/2$ vector, rather than a matrix, so that $g:\mathbb{R}^{n(n+1)/2} \to \mathbb{R}$. Then, I believe the problem is truly unconstrained.

Comment: Sounds like an interesting idea, but I admit I can't currently see how the transformation of a matrix to a truncated vector keeps the problem equivalent to the original one. If you'd like to share the actual function that will be educating for me :)

Comment: For any lower triangular matrix $\tilde{L}$, let $L$ denote the $n(n+1)/2$ vector obtained by taking the entries in the lower triangle of $\tilde{L}$. Now, define $g : \mathbb{R}^{n(n+1)/2} \to \mathbb{R}$ as $g(L) = f(\tilde{L}\tilde{L}^T)$. Then, because $\{\tilde{L}\tilde{L}^T: L \in \mathbb{R}^{n(n+1)/2}\} = \{A: A\geq 0 \} $,  solving the (unconstrained) minimization problem of minimizing $g(\cdot)$ is equivalent (in the sense that I'll get the same minimum value; then I can transform the minimizing vector to a positive semidefinite matrix) with the original problem.