# How to minimize smooth non-convex function over the positive semidefinite cone?

Tags: matrices, nonlinear-optimization, numerical-optimization, positive-semidefinite, non-convex-optimization

I've been stuck with a minimization problem in hand for a while now. It's related to another question of mine ([Ignoring positive (semi)definite condition for optimization](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3827311/799328)), but here I'm asking about much more general directions.

I want to minimize $f:S_n^+ \to \mathbb{R}$ where $S_n^+$ is the positive semidefinite cone, and thus it's a constrained optimization problem. Currently, I'm using the Cholesky decomposition to formulate this into a unconstrained optimization problem as shown in my last comment in https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3827434/799328. I'm pretty sure this isn't really the state of the art, but I'm having trouble pinning down well-established methods under such context. Here, $f$ is smooth (it's $C^\infty$) with uniformly bounded derivatives, but it's not convex. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: I'd be curious to see what your function $f$ is.

Comment: If $f$ polynomial, at least?

Comment: I'm afraid not - I gave a bit more detail on my comment below to @littleO's answers.

Comment: Questions should be self-contained. Details should be included in the question itself. Comments are ephemeral. Readers should not have to read long comment sections to understand what kind of functions you have in mind. If you want people to invest time in answering, you should consider investing time when posting a question.

Comment: Thanks for the helpful comments. I definitely agree with the points you have made. The thing is, as I mentioned below, I can't really share all the details. Moreover, I actually am interested in algorithms that work under such general problems instead of just my problem in hand. Nonetheless, I'll try to be more careful when posting problems. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you want to minimize $f(A)$ subject to the constraint that $A$ is positive semidefinite, and you have the ability to compute the gradient of $f$ (and we note that $\nabla f(A)$ is a matrix, with the same shape as $A$).

One simple approach would be to use the projected gradient method:
$$
A^{k+1} = P(A^k - t \nabla f(A^k))
$$
for $k = 0, 1, \ldots$. Here $P$ is the function that projects a given matrix onto the positive semidefinite cone. (If we work in the space $S_n$ of $n \times n$ symmetric matrices, then $\nabla f(A^k)$ will be symmetric, so $A^k - t \nabla f(A^k)$ will also be symmetric. Projecting a symmetric matrix onto the positive semidefinite cone is a standard operation; you just set the negative eigenvalues equal to $0$.)

You could also use an accelerated projected gradient method such as FISTA, which might converge much faster with only a couple extra lines of code.

Comment: Thanks for the response - do you mind sharing some references? Also, do you agree that transforming the problem to an unconstrained one via Cholesky decomposition is not a great idea?

Comment: @apprentice I'd have to test it to be sure, but I'd guess that the Cholesky decomposition approach won't work as well, and in particular might be expensive due to the need to repeatedly compute the matrix product $L^T L$ (where $L$ is your optimization variable in the unconstrained problem). That matrix multiplication seems expensive, but maybe you have a way to avoid it. I also have an intuition that, even the problem is already non-convex, phrasing the problem in terms of a Cholesky factor of $L$ might make the problem more difficult in some sense.

Comment: @apprentice What I'm most worried about in the solution I wrote here is the possibility that $\nabla f(A^k)$ might not be symmetric. If that's the case, that might require some thought -- might need to figure out what $\nabla f(A)$ should be if we're working in the space $S_n$ rather than working in $R^{n \times n}$. I'd be curious to see your function $f$.

Comment: Hi, again. The problem is a small part of ongoing research with a few coauthors, so I apologize but I can't give you the exact form of $f$. It more or less looks like $-\mathrm{tr}((A+B)^{-1}B^2) + x^T (A+B)^{-1}B^2(A+B)^{-1} x$ where the minimization is over $A$. Here, $B$ is positive definite and $x$ is a known vector. If we differentiate $f$ by ignoring the symmetry condition, I can show that the resulting derivative is indeed not symmetric. However, taking symmetry into consideration isn't too hard.

Comment: Also, while I do agree that having to calculate $L^T L$ for each iteration in not desirable, taking the approach you suggested would require calculating the eigendecomposition for each iteration, which is computationally heavier.  Of course, it all depends on how many iterations we'll need and things like that. I'm not objecting your suggestion; I'm just trying to better understand the problem.

Comment: @apprentice That's true. Yeah, it's not clear to me which approach would work better.

Comment: Thanks for your responses. It seems that I'm not missing something too trivial at least. Also, I guess there's no guarantee of "working" at all, let alone "work better."